# Gmail web client does not display 'High' importance flag

Tags: gmail

How do I get the Gmail web client to display the 'High' importance flag? Is it a setting that needs tweaking?

Comment: 'High importance flag' is not something that's defined in the [email standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).

Comment: @fretje I knew that.. Just didn't know where to link.. so I'll include that in my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GMail [doesn't](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=7fbd738bb86a81b7&hl=en) support these flags, so there is no way to tweak it somehow.

Please note that `High Importance Flag` is something that is not defined in [Internet Message Format](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) (thanks @fretje for the link).